# Variant of Differentiation Under Integral Sign

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives

I was reading Statistical Inference by Casella, Berger, and the following statement appeared on page 70.

> **Theorem 2.4.3.**  Suppose $f(x,\theta)$ is differentiable at $\theta=\theta_0$, that is,
>
> $\displaystyle \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{f(x,\theta_0
>  +\delta)-f(x,\theta_0)}{\delta}=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f(x,\theta)\right|_{\theta=\theta_0}$
>
> exists for every $x$, and there exists a function $g(x,\theta_0)$ and
> a constant $\delta_0>0$ such that
>
> i. $\left|\frac{f(x,\theta_0 +\delta)-f(x,\theta_0)}{\delta}\right|
>  \leq g(x,\theta_0), \textrm{for all } x \textrm{ and } |\delta|\leq
>  \delta_0$,
>
> ii. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,\theta_0)dx<\infty$.
>
> Then
>
> (2.4.2) $\displaystyle
>  \left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,\theta)dx\right|_{\theta=\theta_0} =
>  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f(x,\theta)\right|_{\theta=\theta_0}\right]dx$

Later on, the book explained that condition (i) could be replaced with

> $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
>  f(x,\theta)\right|_{\theta=\theta'}\leq g(x,\theta)$ for all $\theta'$
> such that $|\theta'-\theta|\leq \delta_0$.

What I am confused about is that the dominating function $g$ has $\theta$ in it. I am used to seeing the form of this theorem with only one variable on $g$, such as the one we can see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement).

Basically, I would like to know:

(1) Why does the usual statement, as we see in Wikipedia, disallow having 2 variables on the dominating function $g$? Is there any counterexample?

(2)If there is a counterexample to (1), then what makes the statement in Casella-Berger true?